# How Syncing affects multiple Gmail accounts

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, synchronization

I have multiple Gmail accounts and recently added a GSuite account for a non-profit with which I'm working.

I'd like my bookmarks/folders to appear the same on both laptop and desktop computers for my GSuite account.  However, I DO NOT want my bookmarks for my GSuite to include bookmarks from my personal Gmail account.

What happens if I sync the GSuite account?  Will it only sync bookmarks for the GSuite account across platforms?  Or will it incorporate all my bookmarks for all Gmail accounts into one huge conglomeration of bookmarks?  I really only want the GSuite bookmarks in the GSuite account and no others.  Can I sync that account without bringing in all the personal bookmarks to that account?

Answer (score 1):

That is something that happens when you use the same Window to log in with different email accounts. In the case of Google Chrome you have the ability to create multiple profiles, that means you can have multiple accounts opened at the same time that does not share cookies, cache or bookmarks in this case, each account is independently of each other.

Check the Chrome Help Center article that explains how to create different profiles here https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en.

I cannot tell you how exactly how the sync will affect your accounts but feel free to check this link too https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en could be of help.